# Automatic email from form

Tags: php, mailto

I'm creating a database system where the user can add details within a form and it adds to the database with php. What I want to do however is to send a confirmation email which will also send some of the details within the form. So, when I add details of a student for instance that an email will be send to me that says something along the lines of "A student called "Bob Dabilda" has been added to your database by "agentname"" - I have no problem doing the agent name part since I can just send the session name through, what I have problems is sending forward the student name. Any help appreciated. The following is a version of the add student php part. The adding student form works and the email works separately but I want the email to be sent without the agent having to click a button that says "send email" or anything like that. The database is mysql.

```
require "dbc.php";
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shostfamilyid']);

if($sname && $ssurname && $sgender && $saddress && $sdob && $sblood && $spassport && $shobby1 && $shobby2 && $schildren && $sanimals)
{

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO student VALUES ('','$sname','$ssurname','$sgender','$saddress','$semail','$sdob','$stelephone','$sdiet','$sallergy','$smed','$sblood','$spassport','$shobby1','$shobby2','$shobby3','$ssiblings','$schildren','$srequests','$sanimals','$agent','')");
                header("location: successstudent2.php");
}
    else
    { 
       echo "Check All Required Fields Are Completed"; 
    }
}
```

and this is a copy of the email script that I have working

```
session_start();

error_reporting(0);

if($_SESSION['username'])
{

$to = "from@from.com";
$from = "receive <to@to.com>";

$name = $_POST['webmaster'];
$email = $_POST['email@email.com'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
//generic subject
$subject = "Student Adding";
//header
$header = 'From: '. $from . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1';
//email
$htmlEmail = "
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<font face='Arial' style='font-size:14px;'></font><br>
<font face='Arial' style='font-size:14px;'>A Student was added by ".$_SESSION['username']."   
</font><br><br>
</body>
</html>";
//php mail function
mail($to,$subject,$htmlEmail,$header);
header('Location:members.php'); //forwards user to members.php }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanking you!

Comment: Why not add the mail code inside the same file as the code to add the student to the database? You can call it as a function, passing in the name of the student once the information has been validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You will need to double check all variable names and data being passed below, as this is just an example and probably not functional as-is.**

Create yourself a function in a common file, for example (say this is "functions.php"):

```
<?php
function send_email ($to, $from, $subject, $body) {
/* you'll want to modify the above variables to match what you need in the function */

$to = "from@from.com";
$from = "receive <to@to.com>";

$name = $_POST['webmaster'];
$email = $_POST['email@email.com'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
//generic subject
$subject = "Student Adding";
//header
$header = 'From: '. $from . "\r\n" . 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1';
//email
$htmlEmail = "
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<font face='Arial' style='font-size:14px;'></font><br>
<font face='Arial' style='font-size:14px;'>A Student was added by ".$_SESSION['username']."   
</font><br><br>
</body>
</html>";

//php mail function
mail($to, $subject, $htmlEmail, $header);

}
?>
```

Then change the code that does the insert up a bit:

```
<?php
session_start();
require "dbc.php";
require "functions.php";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shostfamilyid']);

  if ($sname && $ssurname && $sgender && $saddress && $sdob && $sblood && $spassport && $shobby1 && $shobby2 && $schildren && $sanimals) {

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO student VALUES ('','$sname','$ssurname','$sgender','$saddress','$semail','$sdob','$stelephone','$sdiet','$sallergy','$smed','$sblood','$spassport','$shobby1','$shobby2','$shobby3','$ssiblings','$schildren','$srequests','$sanimals','$agent','')");

    if ($query) {
      send_email ($to, $from, $subject, $body); /* modify these as well */
      header("location: successstudent2.php");
      exit();
    } else { 
       echo "Check All Required Fields Are Completed"; 
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I say forget the function or separate page, and just include the PHP script to send an email directly below the INSERT statement.  You shouldn't need to use the "if($_SESSION['username'])", which may be causing your problem anyway.

Comment: While this 'answer' will work - it doesn't help the OP learn and progress. It is very common practice to separate different elements of your application into different files and functions.  By just telling him to 'just include the...' is telling him its okay to take short cuts, which doesn't help him in the long run.  This isn't an attack on you, just my opinion.  Thanks for contributing.  Cheers.